# MIN/MAX with LOOP in Python

Tags: loops, max, min

Please how can I run this code if I need to get the MIN, MAX and SUM of this Loop?

I ran this loop successfully but when I was trying to get the MIN and MAX am getting "int" "the object is not iterable".

for value in range(1,1000):
print(min(value))

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because The min() function returns the item with the lowest value, or the item with the lowest value in an iterable. Means when you are  running your loop your getting i as 1 only and min iterating due to single value. simply you're not having any value for comparison. try to add more [code](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_min.asp).

example,

```
a = list()

for value in range(1,1000): 
    a.append(value)
    if value==999:
           print("min of 1 to 1000 is\t", min(a))
```

Comment: You are awesome Rajan !!!

Answer (score 0):

Min finds the minimum value in an iterable e.g. a list,  min([1,2,3,4])
You are trying to find the minimum value of a single integer i.e. min(1) because the loop returns each value from the range of values you are iterating through